# Unity Android front facing Camera WTF bug

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, camera

I'm developing an app for Android using Unity.
Trying to use front facing camera, getting data from WebCamTexture. Rear-facing works fine, but when I try to flip the camera this awful thing comes out:

```
**bitstream == (int)0xAFAFAFAF
```

as an error in the unity console. Then, WebCamTexture stops working AT ALL, even with the rear-facing camera.
Any idea?

P.S. using Unity 5.3.3p1... could be a Unity bug?

Comment: Try pausing the camera before switching to the front facing camera and resume afterwards.

Comment: I was stopping the camera instead of pausing it...
Man I really hate Android. Now, the rear facing still works after I switch, but still no image from the front facing camera. Not even a black screen

Comment: @TizianoCoroneo, consider the trick of *actually always getting BOTH cameras .. just use two WebCamTexture planes .. and only show the camera you want at a given time!*

Comment: For anyone googling to here, here's the ***exact code*** for getting the spin, rotation, mirroring correct on all platforms: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/773464/webcamtexture-correct-resolution-and-ratio.html#answer-1148424

Comment: @JoeBlow I've just spent 4h adjusting mirroring scaling and everything... otherwise this post would be a HUGE thank you.

Comment: And regarding the front facing camera: the app recognize it exists -> it sees the camera name "Camera 1" (opposed to the main one "Camera 0") -> it sees it is front facing -> it lets me create its webcamtexture -> and then NOTHING HAPPENS. wtf unity?

Comment: ahahahah congrats! I've just solved with a UGLY chain of #if #elif.
About my code, I've discovered it is correct, and it's probably unity's fault for the android front facing camera. It seems webcamtexture just doesn't work so well, so you'll have to program your java snippet to directly call android APIs... and I've no idea on how to do that -- everything works fine on iPhone, btw

Comment: hi Tiziano!  NO!  nonsense, you can get it to work well.  no need to go to native!  see answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## NOTE

for anyone reading, a new (2016) plugin has appeared for Unity,

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/52154

basically you "have to get this" if you want to use device camera in Unity.

Unity's device-camera stuff is the worst thing in Unity - it's literally not even alpha quality. It's the worst thing in Unity and it's ridiculous they included it, it's just a test run.

it's extremely difficult to write a dual-platform true native, high-speed camera plug in. Now that the first one has appeared there's no real alternative than to use it.  Unity's crap is impossible and you can easily spend 2-3 weeks trying to get a rough camera working.

---

Here's a fairly bulletroof approach for the disaster of changing cameras!

```
public void CycleCams()
        {
        StartCoroutine(_cycle());
        }
    
    private IEnumerator _cycle()
        {
        WebCamDevice[] d = WebCamTexture.devices;
        if ( d.Length <= 1 )
            {
            Debug.Log("only one.");
            if (d.Length==1) Debug.Log("Name is " +d[0].name);
            yield break;
            }
        
        Debug.Log("0 " +d[0].name);
        Debug.Log("1 " +d[1].name);
        
        if ( wct.deviceName == d[0].name )
            {
            wct.Stop();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
            wct.deviceName = d[1].name;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
            wct.Play();
            
            nameDisplay.text = "\"" +wct.deviceName +"\"";
            yield break;
            }
        
        if ( wct.deviceName == d[1].name )
            {
            wct.Stop();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
            wct.deviceName = d[0].name;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
            wct.Play();
            
            nameDisplay.text = "\"" +wct.deviceName +"\"";
            yield break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: truly bulletproof. I had almost the same code going on, and the solution was to transform my function in a coroutine and waiting that fraction of a sec. THANK YOU (I'm about to complain with unity for their poor documentation on webcamtexture btw)

Comment: I managed to get also that, but I repeat: with an **UGLY** solution. #if #elif for OSes, and manual checks on device orientation, which camera is working, etc etc

Comment: I got those names by logging Webcamtexture.devices. And it seems that the first element of the array (better to not use its name) it's always the rear facing -> the second one always the front; otherwise, you could check for WebCamDevice.isFrontFacing (or something like that) but I don't know actually how much is reliable

Comment: YES .. you're quite right.  name doesn't matter.  I now just assume that if there are two items, the SECOND one is the selfie camera.  Good thinking. CHEERS

Answer (score 3):

I have to tell you from years of hacking Android ROMs and messing around, you will run into this situation pretty often. And the worst past is due to the firmware the manufactures use, your program might run perfectly on one phone but not the other due to how fragmented the manufacturers are keeping things. Going forward with Marshmallow you will see this less and less due to the constraints they are placing on everyone now. I would recommend just learning the little bit of Java for this portion of your code and calling it directly from Unity.

Comment: I've solved the ugly message, but still no image from the front camera.
Samsung Galaxy S4 GT - i9506  with Android 5.0.1