# in Unity, Android Device Camera not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

when I build my unity project,it's install to my phone and I need to use phone camera but camera not working,actually not opening.
[image]

[image]

AndroidManifest

```
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
</activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"     android:required="false" />
```

Also,I looked available devices with **adb devices** and it shows my device I mean phone

C# script
[image]

I tried to update USB driver in device manager, installed Android SDK API between 9-23,my phones **USB Debugging** is enable.
One more thing,if I tried to look devices in unity console

```
WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
    for( var i = 0 ; i < devices.Length ; i++ )
        Debug.Log(devices[i].name);
```

it's show just my laptop camera and it's open laptop's cam.Any suggest?

Comment: i urge you to buy NatCam from the asset store (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/52154 )  The ***single worst thing*** in Unity is the device camera support.  It's not even a beta.  it's just a placeholder while Unity makes some actual software.  You can spend *literally two or three weeks* trying to get device camera working properly with Unity's built-in joke code.  i would rather go work at McDonald's for a day to make enough money to buy it  :O  it's a HUGE problem given that so many apps of course need the device camera!

Comment: big kudos to @JoeBlow, he helped me a lot with the damned unity camera: see this answer you can extract lots of infos from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845540/unity-android-front-facing-camera-wtf-bug

Comment: i only wish i had more time to help more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait a sec. If you're using Unity Remote to debug your app, it won't work FOR SURE.

The Unity remote app is a streaming service, in reality: it gets user input, sends it to unity, PLAY THE WHOLE THING, and stream back a VIDEO.

That's why it doesn't work: nothing is actually executed on your device.

Just make a build to debug it.

P.S. That's why performance of the Unity Remote it's just plain bad.

P.P.S. : Compression and Quality setting under Unity Remote refers to the video stream compression and quality. That's very `LOL`

Comment: so.. What am I supposed to do? I did not understand , I started to learn unity a week ago.Can you explain again what do you mean remote to debug your app?

Comment: how have you installed the app to your phone?

Comment: In build projects and build and run,after I used ctrl+b everytime

Comment: ok, so it's the right way. BTW the second screen you posted is COMPLETELY unrelated to this problem, that's what I was talking about. It's really better if you just buy a plugin than that diving into spaghetti code

Comment: ooo I got this thanks but one more question, if I don't want to buy plugin and how can I make my own plugin I mean ,I want open my phone camera by itself,not with computer.How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved. :) The following solution works for me.. i think it helps you too. just put this script on camera
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Android;

```
public class permissionscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject dialog = null;
    void Start()
    {
#if PLATFORM_ANDROID
        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.Camera))
        {
            Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.Camera);
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

// here is my device camera script

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class simplecamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    static WebCamTexture backCam;

    void Start()
    {
        WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
        if(backCam == null)
        {
            backCam = new WebCamTexture();
        }
        GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = backCam;
        backCam.Play();
    }
}
```